# How to quickly uplevel json fields in java?

Tags: java, json

I have the following string object (its json) in Java (its pretty printed so it is legible):

```
{
   name: John,
   age: {
     years:18
   },
   computer_skills: {
     years:4
   },
   mile_runner: {
     years:2
   }
}
```

I have an array with 100 people with the same structure.

What is the best way to go through all 100 people and make it such that there is no more "years"? In other words, each object in the 100 would look something like:

```
{
   name: John,
   age:18,
   computer_skills:4,
   mile_runner:2
}
```

In python, I can do something trivial like this in pseudocode:

```
// Iterates through each person
    for person in persons:
// Iterates through each key/value pair k,v
        for k, v in person.items():
            // check if the value is an object {}
            if isinstance(v, dict) and 'years' in v:
                if the value is an object, and there is 'years' as a key nested within, then set the key k to have the value of the nested 'years' field
                person[k] = v['years']
```

In the end, I want to be able to write out that "persons" object back out into a string form (of json).

Is there a simple yet efficient way to do this in java? I would prefer not to create a model object that represents every single field within my object if possible as I like how I dont have to do that in python (unless I have to because its Java).

I like how you can iterate, check if an object has a nested field 'years', if it does, then uplevel it! It looks straightforward.

Comment: If you don't like to work with Objects you can work with a `Map<String, String>`. Keep in mind though, that Java is an Object oriented language...

Comment: Can you show a sample of my question as an answer? I come from a python background so I am not too sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a JSON parser package to get a workable object back, e.g. [quick-json](https://code.google.com/p/quick-json/) or [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) [as shown here](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples). You may need to update the code below to deal with the specific objects you get back, but the same general pattern still applies. The links above contain examples of how to use those libraries.

Assuming you're using a `Map<String,Object>` or something similar, and that `age` is also a `Map<String,Object>`, your answer would look something like this:

```
class MyClass {

    // This changes depending on your entry point, e.g. it's different on Tomcat/JBoss
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // get array of maps using JSON parser ...

        for(Map<String,Object> map:myMapArray) {
            // change value
            map.put('age', ((Map<String,Object>) map.get('age')).get('years'));
        }

        // do other stuff...
    }
}
```

That's not necessarily best practice, so you may want to use a DTO class instead.

Comment: Not sure how iteration could tie into this. This looks very "manual". I would need to have a map.put for every single field that may potentially have that, plus it is nested within an array of them.... not sure how that would be represented by this answer. Is there a way to "check" to see if the value of a root level key is a nested object? How would my string (that contains json) be converted to that "array of maps" to begin with?

Comment: @Rolando I updated the example to deal with an array of Map objects. You can also use this code with an `ArrayList`, depending on whatever you get back from parsing the JSON.

Comment: Can you show how I could be able to convert my initial string that contains the json object to that "Map" to begin with? In python, I just use json.dumps(string) to convert it to a fully accessible object. Is there something that does the same in java?

Comment: @Rolando I updated the answer with links to some JSON libs. Note that the org.json part is split into two links - one to the official project and one to a page of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses Object-Oriented Programming (OOP) and the point of this paradigm is to use **objects**.

Best thing you can do is this:

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private Integer computerSkills;
    private Integer mileRunner;

    /** getters and setters **/

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "{name: "+name+", age:"+age+", 
               computer_skills:"+computerSkills+", mile_runner:"+mileRunner+"}";
    }
```

Then you fullfill your objects and to get back your data just call toString() method.

Comment: This does not look like it does anything to uplevel the nested 'years' key programatically, does not answer the question. How do you fulfill that programatically?